# What is Ruby's bsearch find-minimum and find-any behavior?

Tags: ruby, bsearch

I am reading [the docs for Ruby's bsearch](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Array:bsearch).

It seems when the block returns either true or false, then bsearch works using the "find-minimum" mode. And is there a find-maximum mode?

I don't quite get Ruby's bsearch find-minimum behavior for the 3rd to 5th cases below:

```
[10, 20, 50, 80, 110].bsearch{|a| a >= 25}
=> 50

[10, 20, 50, 80, 110].bsearch{|a| a >= 20}
=> 20

[10, 20, 50, 80, 110].bsearch{|a| a == 20}
=> nil

[10, 20, 50, 80, 110].bsearch{|a| a < 50}
=> nil

[10, 20, 50, 80, 110].bsearch{|a| a <= 50}
=> 10
```

- For the 3rd case, why can't it find `20`?
- For the 4th case, why can't it find `20` also? (the first one less than 50).
- For the 5th case, why does it find `10` and not `20`?

Also, it seems like bsearch will use the `find-any` mode when the block does not return true or false, but return a number. But I can't really understand what it was doing in the docs:

```
ary = [0, 4, 7, 10, 12]
# try to find v such that 4 <= v < 8
ary.bsearch {|x| 1 - x / 4 } #=> 4 or 7
```

like what is `1 - x / 4` and what is it doing?

Answer (score 8):

> - For the 3rd case, why can't it find `20`?
> - For the 4th case, why can't it find `20` also? (the first one less than 50).
> - For the 5th case, why does it find `10` and not `20`?

Your examples 3, 4, and 5 violate the method's pre-condition, so the method can do anything it wants, including return `nil`, return `10`, or format your harddrive. (Although that last one is highly unlikely.)

[The documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) states that:

> the block must return true or false, and there must be an index i (0 <= i <= ary.size) so that:
>
> - the block returns false for any element whose index is less than i, and
> - the block returns true for any element whose index is greater than or equal to i.

Your block violates that condition, therefore the method *cannot possibly* return a meaningful result.

Let's actually step through an example run of `Array#bsearch` for your third case:

```
[10, 20, 50, 80, 110].bsearch{|a| a == 20 }
```

At the first iteration, the algorithm will pick the middle of the array (`50`) and test it against your block:

```
50 == 20 #=> false
```

A value of `false` means that the element that we are searching for, is to the *right* of the current element. Ergo, the element we are searching for must be in the subarray `[80, 110]`. So, we recurse:

```
[80, 110].bsearch{|a| a == 20 }
```

Again, we pick the "middle" element (`110`) and test it against your block:

```
110 == 20 #=> false
```

Since the return value of the block is `false`, we know that the element must be to the right of the current element, *but there is no element to the right* anymore, ergo we know that the element we are searching for, does not exist.

Now for your fourth case:

```
[10, 20, 50, 80, 110].bsearch{|a| a < 50 }
```

At the first iteration, the algorithm will pick the middle of the array (`50`) and test it against your block:

```
50 < 50 #=> false
```

A value of `false` means that the element that we are searching for, is to the *right* of the current element. Ergo, the element we are searching for must be in the subarray `[80, 110]`. So, we recurse:

```
[80, 110].bsearch{|a| a < 50 }
```

Again, we pick the "middle" element (`110`) and test it against your block:

```
110 < 50 #=> false
```

Since the return value of the block is `false`, we know that the element must be to the right of the current element, *but there is no element to the right* anymore, ergo we know that the element we are searching for, does not exist.

Fifth case:

```
[10, 20, 50, 80, 110].bsearch{|a| a <= 50 }
```

At the first iteration, the algorithm will pick the middle of the array (`50`) and test it against your block:

```
50 <= 50 #=> true
```

A value of `true` means that the element that we are searching for, is to the *left* of the current element. Ergo, the element we are searching for must be in the subarray `[10, 20]`. So, we recurse:

```
[10, 20].bsearch{|a| a <= 50 }
```

Again, we pick the "middle" element (`20`) and test it against your block:

```
20 <= 50 #=> true
```

So, the element must still be in the left subarray:

```
[10].bsearch{|a| a <= 50 }
```

will test

```
10 <= 50 #=> true
```

Since the return value of the block is `true`, we know that the element must be to either to the left of the current element *or this element*, but there is no element to the right anymore, ergo we know that the element we are searching for, is this element.

**NOTE**: I *assumed* that `Array#bsearch` would always pick an element as close to the middle as possible and I assumed that for an even number of elements, it would always pick the one right of the middle. But you know what they say about assuming: it makes an ass out of u and me. And indeed, the documentation explicitly states:

> It is undefined which value is actually picked up at each iteration.

So, depending on *which* exact elements actually get picked up at each iteration, the results may actually be different. And that is again not surprising because the block *violates* the preconditions of the method, so there is no way to tell what is going to happen.

> like what is `1 - x / 4` and what is it doing?

This is simply your search criterion. It is `0` for `x == 4`, positive for `x < 4` and negative for `x > 4`. That's exactly what the *find-any* mode needs: positive tells the algorithm it has to look left, negative tells the algorithm to look right, and zero means "you found the range":

> the block must always return a number, and there must be two indices i and j (0 <= i <= j <= ary.size) so that:
>
> - the block returns a positive number for ary if 0 <= k < i,
> - the block returns zero for ary if i <= k < j, and
> - the block returns a negative number for ary if j <= k < ary.size.

Comment: ok, it seems the block provided is not a condition that you hope to have. It is a condition that must **bisect** the array into 2 halves. And by a "point", such that roughly speaking, to the left of this point, it is all `false` and to the right (and including itself), it is all `true`.  This mechanism is to implement a binary search that "always has an answer", and this way, the block provides the condition, and fit into the mechanism of `bsearch` to bisect and bisect.

Comment: I have come to realize it seems there are 2 types of binary search code: one that may not has an answer, and the code has `while low <= high` and the `high = mid - 1`... and then there is another type of binary search code, one that has `while low < high` (it is not `<=`) and it often is `high = mid`... it seems the `bsearch` is doing this "always have an answer" type of binary search (for the find-minimum mode anyway).., I am not sure about the find-any mode yet

Comment: In one simple phrase: the block you provide is to bisect, not to specify what you want. (so it is different from `array.select()`, for example)

Answer (score 4):

Despite documentation, `Array#bsearch` **does not**

> finds a value from this array which meets the given condition

What the method exactly does is it *requires you* to construct such an array `ary` and such a block `blk`, that

### find-minimum mode

... code `ary.map(&blk)` should return an array like

```rb
[false, false, ..., false, false, true, true, ..., true, true]
#                                 ^^^^
```

then code `ary.bsearch(&blk)` will return to you **left-most** array element, which returns `true` for `bkl.call(element)`.

### find-any mode

... code `ary.map(&blk)` should return an array like

```rb
[positive, ..., positive, 0, ..., 0, negative, ..., negative]
#                         ^^^^^^^^^
```

then code `ary.bsearch(&blk)` will return to you **first-met-by-bisect-jump** array element, which returns `0` for `bkl.call(element)`.

---

### Cases 3-5:

> 3. `[10, 20, 50, 80, 110].bsearch{|a| a == 20}`

has no sense as

```rb
[10, 20, 50, 80, 110].map{|a| a == 20}
=> [false, true, false, false, false]
```

> 4. `[10, 20, 50, 80, 110].bsearch{|a| a < 50}`

could be changed to meet **find-minimum mode** requirements:

```rb
[10, 20, 50, 80, 110].reverse.map{|a| a < 50}
=> [false, false, false, true, true]
[10, 20, 50, 80, 110].reverse.bsearch{|a| a < 50}
=> 20
```

> 5. `[10, 20, 50, 80, 110].bsearch{|a| a <= 50}`

could use `reverse` too:

```rb
[10, 20, 50, 80, 110].reverse.bsearch{|a| a <= 50}
=> 50
```

Comment: you mentioned case 4 could be done by `[10, 20, 50, 80, 110].reverse.bsearch{|a| a < 50}` while in real life situation you probably won't reverse it because that's O(n) and if you use O(n) you may as well do a linear search. But maybe this is just an example, that if you use the condition `<` or `<=` the array actually has to be in descending order.  If the array is in ascending order, then the condition in the block is, in general, either `>` or `>=`...

Comment: and if you want the first index of element less than 50, that would be `[10, 20, 50, 80, 110].bsearch_index{|a| a >= 50} - 1
 => 1` and if the return value is -1 that means it is beyond the left end of the array (or that no such element exists that is less than 50). But since there can be no such element that meets the condition at all, the return value of `bsearch` or `bsearch_index` can be `nil`, so the complete code needs to be `(arr = [10, 20, 50, 80, 110]; arr.bsearch_index{|a| a >= 2000} || arr.length) - 1`

Comment: `#reverse` was just a demo of `#bsearch`'s conditions. Of course, you have to adjust your block to your actual sort order.

Comment: I believe, the `#bsearch` doc is unclear and so I tried to explain what actually data it  awaits from you.

Answer (score 2):

In your third example, you are not fulfilling one of the requirement for the find-minimum mode., namely that the block returns `true` for any value that is greater then or equal to your search value.

In the third case, you have switched the values, so that you return `true` for small values and `false` for large values, which again causes undefined behavior.

Similarly, in the firth case, you have switched the order of the equality check. The methods's requirement is that the block returns `true` if the search value is equal to or larger than the search value and `false` if it is smaller.

In general, the bsearch algorithm is quite efficient if you can fulfil all of its requirements, namely that the searched array is sorted and that you specify a suitable block. In that case, it is likely to be more efficient that the basic `find` method.

If you are missing any of its requirements though, you will get undefined behavior and effectively random results. In that case, you will likely have better results with just using [`Enumerable#find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) which also works on Arrays, Hashes, ...